# Failed to execute script using python

Tags: python, opencv, client-server, pyinstaller

I created server and client programs in python. I converted the client.py to exe but when I try to open error display "No module named cv2" but I already installed cv2,  using pip install opencv-python and it's working properly, but somehow it says "failed to execute script", after I converted it to exe, I don't understand why. can someone help me.

Comment: How did you convert your python script to exe? Did you carefully make sure that your cv2 package is installed in the same python environment as the one you are coding in?

Comment: I converted it in cmd using pyinstaller client.py --onefile... Yes it installed in my pycharm environment and it working properly and i also installed in my python environment using  cmd.. Please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.